# Understand JavaScript Recursion and Call Stack in Depth First Traversal

Tags: javascript, recursion, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I have a perfect balanced binary tree:

```
          1
        /   \
       2     5
      / \   / \
     3   4 6   7
```

A simple node structure with DF traversal:

```
function TreeNode(val){
  this.val = val
  this.left = this.right = null
  this.addLeft = function(node){
    this.left = node
  }
  this.addRight = function(node){
    this.right = node
  }
}

function visit(node){
  console.log(node.val)
}

function traverse(node){
  if (node == null) return

  visit(node)

  if(node.left){
    traverse(node.left)
  }
  if(node.right){
    traverse(node.right)
  }
}
```

I create nodes to represent a tree structure:

```
let rootNode = new TreeNode(1)
let node_A = new TreeNode(2)
let node_B = new TreeNode(5)
let node_C = new TreeNode(3)
let node_D = new TreeNode(4)
let node_E = new TreeNode(6)
let node_F = new TreeNode(7)
rootNode.addLeft(node_A)
rootNode.addRight(node_B)
node_A.addLeft(node_C)
node_A.addRight(node_D)
node_B.addLeft(node_E)
node_B.addRight(node_F)
```

Calling `traverse(rootNode)` prints out correctly:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

I understand how recursion works, but am still a little bit confused how JavaScript handles it in the call stack. `traverse(rootNode)` is put in the call stack first, then it reaches the if condition, inside here it checks that `rootNode` has a node left, so it continues down the path until it reaches the final node, which is `TreeNode(3)`. The call stack is like this:

```
|                             |
|                             |
| traverse(TreeNode(3))       |
| traverse(TreeNode(2))       |
| traverse(rootNode)          | 
|_____________________________|        |
```

`TreeNode(3)` does not have any `node.left` or `node.right` so it returns to the if condition, and goes down to check `node.right`, the second condition. Then it sees indeed `TreeNode(2)` has a `node.right` and traverse to `TreeNode(4)` and push it to the stack.

Now this part is confusing me. How does JavaScript keep track of calling `rootNode.right` when `traverse(TreeNode(4)` is completed? In other words, how does it know to switch to the right branch at the end of left branch? Because the output prints `1` to `7`, so the call stack must be:

```
|                             |
| traverse(TreeNode(7))       |
| traverse(TreeNode(6))       |
| traverse(TreeNode(5))       |
| traverse(TreeNode(4))       |
| traverse(TreeNode(3))       |
| traverse(TreeNode(2))       |
| traverse(rootNode)          | 
|_____________________________|
```

But I believe the top of the stack will be the first to pop out and return, so the output should be starting from `7`, not `1`. So my second question is why the console log correctly prints out the result from `1` to `7`.

Comment: It's all relative to the node being passed into the method at that point in time.  The method does not know any other state.  It knows that input, and the method it came from.  When node 4 finishes, it exits back to node 2, because that's who called it, which then exists back to node 1, because that's who called it.  It then starts checking the right node of node 1.

Comment: You could see this visually if you added `console.log('I have returned to node '+ node.val);` immediately after each of your traversal method calls.  http://jsfiddle.net/0zy3fq92/1/

Comment: Javascript cues up all function calls first in the order it reaches them and then evaluates them in backwards order, kind of like digging a hole and then filling it back in. So looking at your diagram of the tree, it makes sense that it would go from 1, to 2, then 3 and four, THEN the original function would shift over to 5, and so on.

Comment: The console.log happens before that of a child node, however the recursive function calls on child nodes are completed in reverse order.  If you move the console.log to the end of the function you would get your reversed sequence.

Comment: @Taplar I added that line inside the `traverse` function even before the base return condition, and it still prints out correctly from `1` to `7`.

Comment: Right, that doesn't change the logic.  It's just creating a visual of which instance of the method call it is returning to, by showing you the value

Comment: @James when putting the `console.log` to the end of the `traverse` function, I get `3 4 2 6 7 5 1`

Comment: While reading on this topic, I understand that JS call stack remembers where the recursive functions is called, and after it returns, it will go back to that environment. It kind of explains how the call stack correctly switches to the right branch when it finishes traversing the left branch.

Comment: But it's still confusing me how it gets the order correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your explanation leaves some important steps out, and I think that's allowing you to reach some invalid conclusions.  In particular, the stack never looks like

```
traverse(TreeNode(7))       
traverse(TreeNode(6))       
traverse(TreeNode(5))       
traverse(TreeNode(4))       
traverse(TreeNode(3))       
traverse(TreeNode(2))       
traverse(rootNode)
```

For the record, none of this is javascript-specific; so really I think this is about improving how well you understand recursion.

Let's step through your `traverse(rootNode)` call in more detail.  So of course the call stack starts out like

```
0: traverse ( node = rootNode ) {
|  =>  if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|      }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_     }
```

Here I'm using notation that makes a few things more explicit:

- I put a number before the call; this way, for example, I could refer to the above call as "call 0 on the stack"
- I show the parameter assignments of each call
- I show the code of the function behind each call, with an arrow `=>` indicating current progress through the code for this particular call.  Here we're about to execute the first instruction.

Following the convention you appear to be using, the most recently-pushed (next-to-pop) item will be shown at the top.

So now since `node` is `rootNode` and that's not `null`, it doesn't just immediately return.  Before any recursion starts, it calls `visit()` on `rootNode`, which goes ahead and prints `1`.  This is one of the things that seems missing from your explanation - nodes are visited (and their values printed) *before* any recursion, so they're being printed as you traverse, as you first reach each node.

Then it checks the `left` and finds a truthy value (in this case, another node object), so it calls `traverse(node.left)` and we end up with a stack like

```
1: traverse ( node = node_A )
|  =>  if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|      }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_     }

0: traverse ( node = rootNode ) {
|      if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|  =>  }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_     }
```

So again we start executing `traverse()` from the beginning with our new `node` value, which is not null so we go ahead and `visit(node)` - which, since `node` is `node_A`, prints 2.  Then it checks `left`, which is truthy (`node_C`) and we get

```
2: traverse ( node = node_C )
|  =>  if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|      }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_     }

1: traverse ( node = node_A ) {
|      if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|  =>  }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_     }

0: traverse ( node = rootNode ) {
|      if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|  =>  }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_     }
```

`node_C` isn't null, so it gets `visit()`ed and this prints `3`.  Now we check `left`, but it's falsey (`undefined`).  So we check `right` and it, too, is falsey (`undefined`).  So we return and now the stack says

```
1: traverse ( node = node_A ) {
|      if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|  =>  }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_     }

0: traverse ( node = rootNode ) {
|      if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|  =>  }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_     }
```

Now we're already midway through the `traverse()` code for call 1 on the stack, so we pick up where we left off (at the `=>`).  So now we check `right`, which is truthy and we get

```
2: traverse ( node = node_D )
|  =>  if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|      }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_     }

1: traverse ( node = node_A ) {
|      if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|      }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_ =>  }

0: traverse ( node = rootNode ) {
|      if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|  =>  }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_     }
```

Now `visit` will print `4` (because `node` is `node_D`, and both `left` and `right` are falsey, so we return to

```
1: traverse ( node = node_A ) {
|      if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|      }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_ =>  }

0: traverse ( node = rootNode ) {
|      if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|  =>  }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_     }
```

But call 1 on the stack has reached the end of it's code, so it returns and we go to

```
0: traverse ( node = rootNode ) {
|      if (node == null) return
|      visit(node)
|
|      if(node.left){
|          traverse(node.left)
|  =>  }
|      if(node.right){
|          traverse(node.right)
|_     }
```

Call 0 picks up where it left off, which means it's about to check `right` (which, I think, answers your original question).  Execution proceeds down the right branch in exactly the same way it proceeded down the left, with the stack at various times containing calls for `rootNode, node_B`, then `rootNode, node_B, node_E`, then `rootNode, node_B` again (but with the code partially executed), then `rootNode, node_B, node_F`, then one last time `rootNode, node_B` (with the code about to finish), then back to `rootNode`, and then the initial call to `traverse` finally returns.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. So each `traverse()` function calls `visit(node)`, which returns the node value out to the console. Since `visit()` completes and returns a value, it will pop out of the stack and the next `traverse()` function will be put in, based on the condition. `traverse(3)` pops out, back to `traverse(2)`, which will call `traverse(4)`. Then `traverse(4)` pops out, back to `traverse(2)`. This function now completes and returns, so back to `traverse(rootNode)`. Then this function will start with the `if(node.right)` line and repeat with the right branch.